# Validate jquery regex - number start with 931

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to validate number that use inputs into input box.
Number must be exactly 12 characters long and start with 931.

```
var reg = /^931[0-9]$/;
var val = $("#sms_number").val();

if (val.length === 12 && reg.test(val)) {                    


}
```

Above is incorrect.

Comment: The main problem here is that `[0-9]` means "any digit between 0 and 9", but repeated just once. Your code would work find if you used `[0-9]+` (meaning "any digit between 0 and 9, repeated 1 or more times")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var reg = /^931\d{9}$/;
var val = $("#sms_number").val();
if (reg.test(val)) {
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without regex too.

```
var val = $("#sms_number").val();

if (val.length === 12 && val.toString().indexOf("931") == 0) {                    

}
```

Simple but probably not as robust as regex solutions

Comment: You are not checking whether the rest 9 characters are valid numbers!

Answer (score 1):

In a concise way the following should work:

```
/^931[0-9]{9}$/.test($("#sms_number").val())? console.log(true): console.log(false);
```

xdazz's answer is correct, but I'd suggest not to use `\d` if you are not trying to accommodate unicode numbers as well. If you are fine with only English numbers (I think that's the way it meant to be, as it uses `931` prefix which is indeed in English) you should use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`. Former is faster.